# Why i can't declare and then assign value to a variable in a class without any method IN JAVA

Tags: java

It may sounds crazy but what i really want to do is just declare and initialize a member variable within a public class and then re-assign this variable with another value which is quite realistic in C. But it fails in Java.

```
public class App {

    public int id=6; // got an error of "Syntax error on token ";", , expected"
    id=7; 
}
```

But this could be done within a method. For example:

```
public class App {

    public int id=6; 
    // id = 7; 

    public void method() {
        id = 7;  // that's okay 
    }
}
```

So, what really perplexing to me is that what makes the difference of using a method there in stead of re-assigning the member variable in the next line. I'm really looking forward to learn the insight conception of it if there exists any.

**Difference to duplicate: I want to learn the methodology why OOPL forces to use methods/constructors if I try to re-assign any variable after initializing it ???**

Comment: Are you sure that is where it fails and not on `id=7;` (which is commented out in the "working" version? Also, since you're talking about an error message it would be wise to include the message in your question.

Comment: Why did you tag this `c`?

Comment: The code you have posted is legal Java. The commented-out code is an assignment statement, which is a statement, and statements must be inside constructors or methods. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I don't get it... I think it's obvious what he's asking. He is asking why he can't do "id=7;" in the first snippet.

Comment: "within a public class and then re-assign this variable with another value which is quite realistic in C" - C does not even support classes, etc. You mean C++? That is a different language.

Comment: You don't need a method, you just need braces.  But that's equivalent to putting it in the constructor, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in object oriented programming the 'class' represents a description of a particular object. If we use the analogy of a car, think of it as the 'blueprint'.

The blueprint does a number of things:

- Describes what kind of properties the object can have (so a car might have color and speed)
- Describes what things the object can *do* (its 'methods')
- Describes what the initial state of the object is each time it is created

The line `public int id=6` does the first and the last of these. It says that any `App` object must have an `id` property, and its initial state is the value `6`. If you then put the line `id=7` in the class definition this isn't part of the blue print - it doesn't make sense to say that the default value of `id` is 6, and then decide it is 7 - so this is an error.

In Java, as with many object oriented languages, actual code that modifies state MUST take place inside a 'method', since every time something is happening in OOP, it is an 'object' *doing something*.

**Edit**

Your error is

> Syntax error on token ";", , expected

This makes sense - it sees the following code

```
 public int id=6;

 id=7;
```

And thinks what you really meant to do was

```
 public int id=6,

 id=7;
```

Which would be the same as

```
 public int id=6, id=7;
```

Of course this would generate another error probably unless you changed the name of the second definition.

Comment: So, according to Your answer,  if I use  'public static int id=6'  then it should work. But , still it fails.

Comment: Did you remove the `id = 7` line?

Comment: @W.Jack No, the issue is not actually with that line, it just points at that line because the following line confuses it; see my edit

Comment: "In object oriented programming the 'class' represents a description of a particular object" - That's not true for all OOPL. There are different approaches for OOP, especially for full-grown OOPL like Python where classes are objects themselves.

Comment: No. As i used  **static**  so the variable **id**  should not be the property of any particular instance rather it would also work for the class itself. so **id=7** should work in this case....

Comment: @Olaf ok, that's fair. But is it not *generally* the case?

Comment: @W.Jack No, because in Java, you 'do things' in methods, like I've already explained. The method body is only for specifying the properties and methods of the class.

Answer (score -2):

On root level you can declare only methods and field variables. If you want to change the value of the variable when the object is initualized you need to do this in constructor:

```
public class App {
      public int id=6; 

      public App() {
            id=7; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes,,  but constructor is  kind of methods by the way. So, why I must use methods in this case ?? Is it by convention in Java ??